# Powershell command Publish-AzWebApp not publishing apllication

Tags: .net, azure, powershell

I have a .Net 6 Web API application, I am able to publish it via Visual Studio 2022 to Azure Application service and then use the application.

Now I want to automate it. My powershell creates a zip file with all the necessary files inside.

Then I call

```
Publish-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName  MyResourceGroup -Name MyWebApi -ArchivePath D:\projects\MyWebApi\publish\8044a70f-f3fc-4271-b37a-f0b2658d9192.zip
```

But after it finishes I go to Azure ftp and wwwroot folder is empty and the application does not work.

Am I using the cmdlet the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a .NET Core 6 Web Application in Visual Studio 2022 and made to the Zip File.

- Created the App Service using PowerShell Commands:

[image]

- Deployed the above Web Application to this App Service using the Command from the local Windows PowerShell:

[image]

[image]

#### Updated Answer:

You can deploy using Cloud Shell, but Azure Cloud Shell has some [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cloud-shell/limitations).

[image: AzurecloudShell]

We need to upload the Zip File to Azure `Clouddrive` if using the **Azure Cloud Shell** and then deploy the Web App to the particular app service from that `Clouddrive` location.

Comment: Does it mean that the only way to deploy a web application in zip file is *Invoke-RestMethod -Uri* https://mywebappname.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/api/zip/site/wwwroot/* ?

Comment: Hi @harikrishnarajoli-mt, Invoke-RestMethod works without deploying to _Clouddrive_. It looks like it is the only way to deploy from local drive via zip file

Answer (score 0):

This is how to deploy web api to Azure from local directory in zip file

```
[xml]$publishingProfileXMl = Get-AzWebAppPublishingProfile -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $webAppName -Format "WebDeploy"

$userName = $publishingProfileXMl.publishData.publishProfile.userName[0]
$password = $publishingProfileXMl.publishData.publishProfile.userPWD[0]
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username, $password)))

$apiUrl = "https://${webAppName}.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/api/zip/site/wwwroot/"
$headers = @{"Authorization"="Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo;}

Write-Host ">------------------------------ Stopping '${webAppName}' Web Application..."
Stop-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $webAppName
Write-Host ">------------------------------ Publishing '${webAppName}' Web Application..."
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers $headers -UserAgent $userAgent -Method PUT -InFile $zipPath -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
Write-Host ">------------------------------ Starting '${webAppName}' Web Application..."
Start-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $webAppName
```

Comment: Why using Invoke-RestMethod instead of Publish-AzWebApp?

Comment: @AlexMethod because Publish-AzWebApp didn't publish

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Visual Studio, `Publish-AzWebApp` will not create the necessary Azure resources by itself.  You will need to create the resource separately, either via an [ARM Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template), other cmdlets such as `New-AzWebApp`, or even manually via the Azure portal (although that's not ideal from an automation standpoint).  In addition, you may also need to create supporting resources, such as a storage account (where the code actually lives) and a server farm resource.

Once you have the resources deployed, `Publish-AzWebApp` can be used to *update* the code in your web app.

Comment: All the resources were created. The problem is that the code wasn't uploaded.